# Is there any drawback of not closing the file after reading it?

Tags: python

I often do not close the file after reading it

```
for line in open(FileName):
    # do something
```

I also reopen the file again in the same program.

```
for line in open(FileName):
    # do something else
```

My question is whether there are any drawbacks in this approach? 
I have seen posts that claim that file should be open with `with`

```
with open(FileName) as fp:
```

But what is the advantage of this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some situations, you might get away with not closing the file without experiencing adverse effects.  CPython (the most popular Python implementation) will close the file immediately after the loop when using `for line in open("filename"):`, provided no further references to the file exist.  In other Python implementations, closing the file may be delayed, but it will eventually be closed.

There are a few issues, though:

1. Sometimes hidden references to a file continue to exists.  If an exception is thrown in a function, the traceback associated with the exception contains a reference to the execution fram of the function, so all local variables continue to exist – this may keep files open for longer than expected even in CPython.
2. You may run out of file descriptors when opening many files, since you don't have control over the time they get closed again.
3. Python 3.2 or above will raise a `ResourceWarning` for every file that was not closed (this warning can be disabled, but anyway).

In summary, it's simply not worth the trouble.  Always use `with`, and forget about these issues.  There is enough to keep in mind while prgramming anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I like your last line the most.

Comment: re issue #1: what happens to an open file, in a local variable, in a stack frame, protected by a `with` statement, during an exception?

Comment: @thebjorn: It gets closed during stack unwinding, before any exception handler *outside* of the `with` block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Re using `with`:

The main advantage of opening/managing files using `with` is that they are *automatically closed* for you when you exit the "block" assocated with the `with`. And the file is also closed in case you encounter an *exception*.

Leaving files unclosed is untidy programming.

Note, especially in the case of files you are *writing* to, you may not get all of the data you expected in your output file since an unclosed file may not have had all of its buffers flushed (which happens automatically as part of closing a file), resulting in only a partial output file.

So, while you don't have to use `with` for opening files, it does make it easier to manage them and also takes care of closing your files, i.e., one less thing for you to worry about, which is why it is recommended.